# Embedding a part of a dynamic webpage (Kibana) into my own site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kibana

My colleague is working on this project to create a simpler version of an already existing site called "Kibana". Some of it's graphs to be in particular are to be re-made. What I was thinking is that, will it be possbile for us to just capture the graph of kibana into our simpler html site by using jQuery.

PS: By capture I mean, display the whole dynamic AJAX portion of the site (graphs) in our own html page.

Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function 
{
('#div_in_our_html_page').load('div_for_the_graph_in_kibana');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kibana is far more than the graphs displayed.  There is a lot of dynamic data going on.

Comment: @JonasGrumann That's not correct in this case.  Kibana runs entirely client-side.

Comment: Hi Brad, I know Kibana is a whole lot more. But simply putting, I want embed a part of the whole web page inside my html page. Is that possible in theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Kibana 3.1.2. I copied the root folder after renaming it to kibana in my web application. I added a link in my application so it would load the dashboard I am interested in showing. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/729

Basically, you need to embed the dashboard in an iframe on your site.

If you can't actually access the server Kibana's running on, try setting your iframe's margin-top and margin-left to negative values to capture the portion of the page with your graph, and disable scrolling with scrolling="no" (not technically html5 compatible, but it should work in most major browsers).